# Get max date for each line in a table in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I edited my answer so the solution for my question is:

```
select  DISTINCT e.Cod_proiect
     , p.Descriere
     , p.Stare
     , p.ClientService
     , e.Data
  from ExpPoz as e 
  join Proiecte as p 
    on e.Cod_proiect=p.Cod_proiect 
             join ( 
                     select cod_proiect, max(data) maxDt 
                     from ExpPoz
                     group by cod_proiect 
                  ) latest on latest.cod_proiect = e.cod_proiect and latest.maxDt = e.Data and p.Stare='I'
```

Which gives the following error: Subquery returned more than 1 value
I am trying to get every line with the maximum date.

I have the following table structure:

```
a    date1
a    date2
a    date3
b    date4
b    date5
```

The output should be, supposing that date3 and date5 are the oldest/biggest:

```
a   date3
b   date5
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your query doesn't match the sample table data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL select only rows with max value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

Comment: I just putted an example of structure. The table is to big.

Comment: my example is using 2 tables not just one..that's why returns the error : Subquery returned more than 1 value

Comment: You really should start using ANSI-92 style joins, they have been available for more than 25 years now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
select  e.Cod_proiect
      , p.Descriere
      , p.Stare
      , p.ClientService
from ExpPoz as e join Proiecte as p on e.Cod_proiect=p.Cod_proiect 
                 join ( 
                         select cod_proiect, max(data) maxDt 
                         from ExpPoz
                         group by cod_proiect 
                      ) latest on latest.cod_proiect = e.cod_proiect and latest.maxDt = e.Data
where p.Stare='I'
```

Please note that the way you have written the `joins` is very old and it is better and more clear if you use the modern `join` style. 
In this query I selected everything you need and joined once with the latest record per `cod_proiect`.

Comment: The multi-part identifier "p.Stare" could not be bound.

Comment: see my edited answer..just needed a distinct e.Cod_proiect

Answer (score 0):

You might try this:

```
SELECT cod_proiect,
       MAX(data)
FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT
         ep.cod_proiect,
         ep.data
  FROM   ExpPoz   ep
  JOIN   Proiecte pr
    ON   ep.cod_proiect = pr.cod_proiect
   AND   pr.stare = 'I'
)
GROUP BY cod_proiect;
```